# Convert Timestamp date MyDate class using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Let i have class,

```
class MyDate {
    org.joda.DateTime date;
    Character flag;
}
```

and i have field `MyDate` in main class

```
class MainClass {
    MyDate optionalDate;
}
```

What annotations do I need if date is stored in Column `DATE_COL`, and flag is stored in column `FLAG_COL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What annotations do I need if date is stored in Column DATE_COL, and flag is stored in column FLAG_COL?

You need to use the `@Column` annotation. e.g. `@Column(name="DATE_COL")` and `@Column(name="FLAG_COL")`.

Comment: No no. What annotations do I need for field 'optionalDate'? One field but two columns!

Comment: Check out the annotations like `@Embeddable`, `@Embedded`.